# Sending string via ftp : getting error

Tags: iphone, ftp, nsstring

I'm trying to send a string via ftp using the code below but I'm getting an error:

```
{

    //miscellaneous lines of code.....
    //Convert contents of shopping cart into a property list
    [Cart serializeCart];

    //now need to transport the propertyList to the webserver
    //first step is get the serialized propertylist from the documents folder
    NSString *pathToSerializedCart = [rootPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"serializedCart.plist"];

    NSString *shoppingCartString;

   if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:pathToSerializedCart])
   {
       NSLog(@"ERROR:\nCouldnt find serialized cart in documents folder.");
   }
   else 
   {
       NSData *serializedData = [NSData            dataWithContentsOfFile:pathToSerializedCart];
       shoppingCartString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:serializedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   }

   NSLog(@"%@", shoppingCartString);
   //Now that the cart is converted into a string. it is ready for transport
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"ftp://username:password@domainName.com/folder/serializedCart.xml"];

   BOOL OK =[shoppingCartString writeToURL:url atomically:NO encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];   
   if(!OK) {
       NSLog(@"Error writing to file %@ , error = %@", url, [error localizedFailureReason]);
   }
```

I'm getting the following console output for this code:

```
Error writing to file ftp://username:password@domainName.com/folder/serializedCart.xml , error = (null)
```

One of the variables: `_domain` in this error object in the last line when, I mouse over it during debugging says `NSCocoaErrorDomain`

I'm not sure how to debug this. 
Could someone give any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `writeToURL:..` methods don't support the `FTP` protocol. You'll have to use other mechanisms to write the string content onto an ftp server. You can look at tools such as [`ios-ftp-server`](http://code.google.com/p/ios-ftp-server/) to handle such uploads. You can also look at this [`sample code`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009243-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) from Apple.