# How can I upload a string to an FTP server and save it there from within an iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, ftp

I've been attempting this for a week now, and it seems the more I ask online, the more confused I get, and the more the answers vary. Because of this, I'd like to ask just a simple question: **How can an iPhone app that has an XML file saved in an instance of NSString send it from the iPhone to an FTP server?** I mean, what APIs or tools can I use to do this?

Please suggest the simplest ones as I'm new to iPhone development. I would appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first try using `-[NSString writeToURL:atomically:encoding:error:]` with an `ftp:` scheme URL.

If that failed, I would use `CFFTPStream`, which is expressly designed to work with FTP.

You might want to check out [s7ftprequest](http://code.google.com/p/s7ftprequest/) or Apple's [Simple FTP Sample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Listings/Read_Me_About_SimpleFTPSample_txt.html) project. Both were suggested by answers to ["Upload File to FTP Server on iPhone"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266176/upload-file-to-ftp-server-on-iphone).

Comment: That wont work I have already tried it. See my code here from that try:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6406350/sending-string-via-ftp-getting-error

Comment: I suspected the `NSString` method might fail, which is why I supplied a fallback solution. `CFFTPStream` will most definitely work. `s7ftprequest` will be a ton easier to use, though.